# paper.js angular.js canvas only updates on canvas mouseover

Tags: angularjs, paperjs

I have set up an app with angular.js. I am creating a menu via ng-repeat. Every link calls a function inside a directive that uses paper.js to draw text to canvas.

But canvas not updates until i move the mouse around browser. The function that draws on to the canvas is calling immediately, but the canvas shows nothing without mouse moves away from the link?

angular.js controller that calls draw function inside directive:

```
.controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, $location, $http, WorkService) {
  $scope.works = [];
  $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/v1/work'}). //collects all works
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.works = data.objects;
  });
  $scope.setTitle = function(work) { 
      $scope.currentTitle=work.title;  

          $scope.writeTitle(work.title);

  };


})
```

angular.js directive:

```
.directive('draw', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function postLink($scope, element, attrs) {

        $scope.writeTitle = function(inText){
            var letters = inText.split(''); 
            for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
            var text = new PointText(new Point(getRandom(0, 200), getRandom(0, 100)));
            text.content = letters[i];
            text.style = {
                fontFamily: 'Arial',
                fontWeight: 'normal',
                fontSize: 14,
                fillColor: 'red',
                justification: 'center'
            };

            }

        }



        function getRandom(min, max) {
              return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
            }


        function initPaper() {

            paper.install(window);
            paper.setup('canvas');
        }


        initPaper();


    }
};

});
```

the  menu in my base.html that calls controller function to draw:

```
<div ng-controller=NavCtrl>
        <nav>
             <a href='#/bilgi'>bilgi</a>
             <a  ng-click="setTitle(work)" href='#/ardiye/{{work.id}}'  ng-repeat='work in works'>{{$index+1}}</a>
        </nav>

    </div>
```

---- UPDATE ----

I have added:

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">

function onFrame(event) {

}
</script>
```

this empty onFrame function to base.html and now the canvas updates normally. But why?

Comment: Please provide the code that you're having a problem with.

Comment: ok. I have edited my post with the code. Canvas updates only if i move mouse over the canvas.

Comment: I have found that on two conditions the canvas gets updated. One is when mouse cursor moves over the canvas and the other is when mouse cursor is over page margins around the body element...

Comment: Can you post the HTML code you are using to apply your "draw" Directive?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/burkesk/ffNYP/11/  does this fiddle help?

Comment: i encounter the same problem. did u find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

**Have you tried updating the View?**

I had an issue on Firefox and IE11 with the canvas not updating until a mouseover after I initiated some operation.

I just called `paper.view.update()` at the end of each function and it all went down allright.

If this is the issue, it has nothing to do with Angular

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code inside your directive function within a `scope.$apply()` function.  This will make sure that it updates the UI.

One other thing, it is convention inside a directive to use to use `scope` (no dollar sign) instead of `$scope`.   In a controller you are actually passing in the named object $scope.  Angular needs to know the actual names of the objects you want to inject.  Inside your directive's link function, however, the actual names do not matter.  This is because inside link attribute the parameters are passed in a specific order: `scope, element, attributes`. You could use `foo, bar, baz` if you wanted but they will still be resolved as `scope, element, atttributes`.

With this in mind you could actually use `$scope` but realize that you can do that only because of the order it is inside the function parameter list.

```
link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) 

        scope.writeTitle = function(inText){
            scope.$apply(function () {
              var letters = inText.split(''); 
              for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
              var text = new PointText(new Point(getRandom(0, 200), getRandom(0, 100)));
              text.content = letters[i];
              text.style = {
                  fontFamily: 'Arial',
                  fontWeight: 'normal',
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fillColor: 'red',
                  justification: 'center'
              };
            });
     }
```

Comment: And i get error Error: $rootScope:inprog
Action Already In Progress

Comment: And i have figured out that i can not do built in point and size mathematical operations. The paper.js doc says if using paper with plain js this is the expected behaviour. But i can reach everthing without the paper prefix... I am confused. Am i using paperscript or plain js?